# Is " return await Task.Run(() => PartialView()) " necessary?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I know a little about async and await in c#. But I saw this method of returning the view as shown. So I would like to know how this method works?

I have done this,

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> SamplePartialPage()
{
    ViewBag.countryList = await db.CountryList.ToListAsync();
    return PartialView();
}
```

but not this.

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> SamplePartialPage()
{
    ViewBag.countryList = await db.CountryList.ToListAsync();
    return await Task.Run(() => PartialView());
}
```

Comment: You should change the return type to `PartialViewResult` instead of `Task<PartialViewResult>`

Comment: sure. I too felt like it was not necessary. but i would like to know why do some people use the second behavior?

Comment: @Thameem When they need to force the code to execute on another thread and/or when they don't quite have a clue about what they're doing.

Comment: I've seen this in the past where the method at one point had no asynchronous calls (`await`) and the author *unfortunately* added the `await Task.Run` in order to silence the compiler warning rather than de-Taskifying the method (removal of `async` and modified return type). It *could* be the case here that the method was once fully sync and it was not fixed when async population of `countryList` was introduced. But it's hard to speculate about other people's intentions...

Comment: @Sisir If they did that then the method could not be `async` and they would not be able to `await` the `ToListAsync`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know a little about async and await in c#.

I recommend reading my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [async best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). There are also lots of other great resources. Since you're on ASP.NET, you should also read [async on ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net).

> i would like to know why do some people use the second behavior?

On ASP.NET, there isn't a good reason to use `await Task.Run`. `await Task.Run` schedules work to a thread pool thread and frees up the current thread. But on ASP.NET, the code *was already running* on a thread pool thread, so `await Task.Run` just causes a thread switch and provides no benefits at all.

This *is* a valid pattern in other scenarios; specifically, if you're on a UI thread in a client-side GUI app, then using `await Task.Run` is a normal pattern to push work off the UI thread and keep it responsive.

Comment: Also the example looks like [I/O-bound work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#recognize-cpu-bound-and-io-bound-work).

Comment: @aepot: Creating the view is CPU-bound, but it is so short that even if you *wanted* to free up the thread via `Task.Run`, the overhead may make the result slower anyway.